# Deadlock happens on 1 single table with 2 users doing simple statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, deadlock, database-deadlocks

**Final solution**
What we did actually was to bypass the line by line insert by creating a work table & session ID, and having a stored proc that DELETE and INSERT from the temp table to the main table all at once. No more deadlocks!
Final process :

- DELETE FROM TheTable_work (with sessionID, just in case…)
- INSERT INTO TheTable_work (line by line with ADODB)
- I call a stored procedure that does :

  - BEGIN TRANSACTION
  - DELETE FROM TheTable (with some
    conditions)
  - INSERT INTO TheTable FROM TheTable_work (1
    statement)
  - COMMIT
- DELETE FROM TheTable_work (clean up)

We do think it's because of index lock but I am waiting for confirmation from DBA (explanation [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2008/07/30/the-anatomy-of-a-deadlock.aspx)).

Isolation levels did not change nothing (we tried all of possibilities, even turning on and off READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT)

---

I am having an application that causes a deadlock into my database when 2 users "write" to the database at the same moment. They do not work on the same data, because they have different id, but they work on the same table.

User 1 (id = 1), User 2 (id = 2)

**Process**

```
User 1 does : 1 DELETE statement, followed by 3000 INSERT
User 2 does : 1 DELETE statement, followed by 3000 INSERT 

User 2 DELETE in the middle of user 1 INSERT (example : after 1500). Result in Deadlock.
```

**Statements** (examples, but they work)

```
DELETE FROM dbo.TheTable WHERE id = 1  /* Delete about 3000 lines */
INSERT INTO dbo.TheTable (id, field2, field3) VALUE (1 , 'value2','value3')
```

I use ADODB (Microsoft Access...) so I do a simple query execute , example :

```
ConnectSQLServer.Execute "DELETE or INSERT statement"
```

**Error Message**

```
Run-time error '-2147457259 (80004005)':
Transaction (Process ID76) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

**Other informations**

- There is no transaction involved, only simple INSERT or DELETE query,
  one by one
- There is no RecordSet involved, nor open
- We tried to looked for a deadlock trace but no graphic showed up, a DBA tries to understand why
- I'd like to understand why they deadlock each other and not just "wait" until the other one is finished! How can I do better operations ? =)
- Access : it's a access front-end with SQL-Server backend. No linked tables, vba code pushed queries via ADODB connection.

**Edit : Deadlock graph**
On the left we have 1 (of 3000) INSERT statement, on the right one DELETE. 
[image: Deadlock graph]

**UPDATE**
I deleted an index on a column that is used in the DELETE statement and I can not reproduce the deadlock anymore! Not a clean solution, but temporary. We think about INSERT 3000 lines in a temp table then copy from temp table to TheTable all at once (DELETE and INSERT in a stored procedure).

Thanks,

Séb

Comment: What does "only simple INSERT or DELETE query, one by one" mean? That sounds like maybe you are using a loop for this? But I am also a bit confused. 99.999% of your question is clearly sql server but then you mention Access. Is Access the front end and all the processing is in sql server?

Comment: Get a [deadlock graph](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/capturing-deadlock-information/)

Comment: If you want to understand a deadlock, you need a [deadlock trace](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/capturing-deadlock-information/). No two ways about it. An educated guess about what the deadlock is and how best to fix it is possible if you have a lot of experience, but even then it's dangerous because you can still easily guess wrong. Without a trace, my educated guess would be that your table has multiple indexes, and the `INSERT` and `DELETE` lock them in different, incompatible orders, something you typically solve by strategically increasing locking. *But that's a guess*.

Comment: Are you connected with sql server 2012 and use access  as a linked tables?

Comment: @SeanLange and M. Hassan : Sorry for Access confusion : it is only the front end, and no linked tables, we use VBA to do ADODB queries to SQL-Server. Yes there is a "loop" pattern because the user input stuff and it generates about 3000 INSERT statement, all sent at once to the database (one after the other).

Comment: Jeroen : Thanks, we just got a deadlock graph, but no trace yet. I will attach image to main post.

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE` will hold an Update lock on the pages :

> **Update (U)**
>
> Used on resources that can be updated. ***Prevents a common form of
>   deadlock that occurs when multiple sessions are reading, locking, and
>   potentially updating resources later.***

And `INSERT` will hold an intent/exclusive lock on the same pages.

> **Exclusive (X)**
>
> Used for data-modification operations, such as INSERT, UPDATE, or
>   DELETE. ***Ensures that multiple updates cannot be made to the same
>   resource at the same time.***
>
> **Intent**
>
> Used to establish a lock hierarchy. The types of intent locks are:
>   intent shared (IS), ***intent exclusive (IX)***, and shared with intent
>   exclusive (SIX).

If you wish to run both queries at the same time,
each will have to wait for the other at a given time.

I suggest you to run each insert in a seperate transaction if no rollback is needed for the whole set of inserts.
Or, try to remove parallelization, or do these operations at different times.

To make short :
1) Try to make sure each INSERT is correctly commited before going to the next one.
2) Or try to avoid doing both operations at the same time

Another guess would be to adjust the Transaction Isolation Level for the sessions that produce the problem. Check the following documentation.

Reference :
[Lock Modes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519(v=sql.105).aspx)
[Transaction Isolation Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Hybris95. We do not use transaction, we only sent each query one after the other to SQL Server. I understand that 1 INSERT and 1 DELETE happens at the same time from 2 different users cause the deadlock. This would be hard to block, well because the query strings are sent by the client side and not on a server side. I wonder if they could be totally independent (happening one after the other). I tried with BEGIN TRANS and COMMIT theses 2 statements caused a deadlock. Other option would be to have a "setting" in database each process would call to ask if they can write.

Comment: Seems like your applications implicitely create a transaction for the whole insert/delete statements. Using a transaction for the whole block will generate a DeadLock, but will also ensure that a rollback will rollback the whole context and not just the last inserted row.

Comment: Also : you ARE using transaction, just not explicitely. Your application manages the transaction level itself, see the Edit of my answer considering this option

Comment: Thanks for the precision! I understand I am using a transaction and I should manage it myself instead of leaving that to ADODB ! I go back to work on that! :)

Comment: have you seen my update UPDATE? By deleting the index I fixed the problem. Thou I do not want to make it a permanent solution. 
I deleted an index on a column that is used in the DELETE statement and I can not reproduce the deadlock anymore! Not a clean solution, but temporary. We think about INSERT 3000 lines in a temp table then copy from temp table to TheTable all at once (DELETE and INSERT in a stored procedure).

Comment: Also what was the associated object_id 72057594071482368 ? Maybe your index wasn't it ? You can check `sys.objects` to find out (if still in it)

Comment: Haven't found out yet for sys.object. What we did actually was to bypass the line by line insert by creating a temp table & session ID, and having a stored proc that DELETE and INSERT from the temp table to the main table all at once. No more deadlocks!

Comment: objid was referencing TheTable.